# Loop and generate table cells

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
I have a table that looks like the following: 

<table class = "rota">
    <thead>
        <th>Date</th> 
        <% @hospitals.each do |hosp| %>
        <th><%= hosp.name%></th>
        <% end %>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%- if @rota_days.blank? %>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="<%= @hospitals.count %>">No rota day</td>
        </tr>
        <% end -%>
        <% @dates.each do |date| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= date.inspect %></td>

            <% end %>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Which outputs the following:

[image: the output]

I am trying to generate blank rows that contain empty cells. I cannot seem to identify where I am going wrong. What is the best possible solution

Updated version

```
<table class = "rota">
    <thead>
        <th>Date</th> 
        <% @hospitals.each do |hosp| %>
        <th><%= hosp.name%></th>
        <% end %>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%- if @rota_days.blank? %>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="<%= @hospitals.count %>">No rota day</td>
        </tr>
        <% end -%>
        <% @dates.each do |date| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= date.inspect %></td>
            <% (1..@hospitals.count).each do %> 
                <td></td> 
            <% end %> 
           </tr> 
            <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ending your loop too soon and you'll need a td for each th so change:

```
<% @dates.each do |date| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= date.inspect %></td>
     <% end %>
  </tr>
```

To:

```
<% @dates.each do |date| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= date.inspect %></td> 
    <% (1..@hospitals.count).each do %>
      <td></td>    
    <% end %>       
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What I am essentially trying to do is produce the following: http://i.imgur.com/lumIt.jpg As you can see I have the headers. I have two things that I need to do. 1) Generate the dates vertically, 2) Generate the rows to contain empty cells. Once I have generated the cells.

Comment: Just load the dates into the first column and apply CSS to get that desired effect. Edit your question with the output html that you're getting for 1) your original code and 2) trying my answer.

Comment: It did not work for me and the output is exactly the same. http://i.imgur.com/KseiT.png. I updated my question that includes your code

Comment: That doesn't help, I need to see the **output html** from your code and mine. Go to the webpage and click view source and copy and paste the html that it outputs for the entire table. Also how are you setting your @dates variable? It doesn't seem to have any dates in it...

Comment: This is the output of your code https://gist.github.com/3996138 and this is my output of my code https://gist.github.com/3996165

Comment: Ok it looks like we have your HTML formatted properly with my code based on the output on your gist. The only reason it's not looping properly and displaying dates is because your `@dates` variable isn't being set properly, if you add the statement `<%= debug @dates %>` to your view you can inspect what it's being set to. Anyways that's more to do with your controller code and that would be a different question if you're still having problems.